# How to block the close event when selecting a date in angular material datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to block the close event which closes the calendar when selecting a date in angular material datepicker.

I've tried like,

```
// template
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker (closed)="onCalendarClose(picker)"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

// component
onCalendarClose(picker: MatDatepicker<Date>): void {
  picker.open();
}
```

But this just literally reopens the calendar after closing it, which blinks the screen and shows back the calendar. So I'm wondering if I can block the close event upon selecting a date.

**Update:**
I'm using Angular 8, Angular Material 8.1.4

Answer (score 1):

What material version you are using?Because this ability to output the closed event is in `material 5.0.0-rc.1` .If you are not having this material version installed then update it with this version.

Comment: I'm using 8.1.4 which emits `closed` event but it blinks the calendar if I reopen the calendar on the `closed` event callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the .close() method in component:

```
picker.close = () => {};
```

But first save it, and then restore it in ngOnDestroy()!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class=" p-0 down-cont"  style="
        font-family: 'SF Pro Text', 'Titillium web', sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;min-width:180px;
        ">
            <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
            <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="rangePicker">
              <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" [max]="date2"  (dateInput)="clickDate1
                ($event)"  (dateChange)="clickDate1($event)" [(ngModel)]="date1">
              <input matEndDate placeholder="End date"  [min]="date1" (dateInput)="clickDate2
                ($event)"  (dateChange)="clickDate2($event)" [(ngModel)]="date2">
            </mat-date-range-input>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="rangePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-date-range-picker #rangePicker>
            <mat-date-range-picker-actions>

            <button mat-raised-button  matDateRangePickerApply (click)="addDate2()">Apply</button>
            <button mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel (click)="picker.close()">Cancel</button>
            </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
            </mat-date-range-picker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the _applyPendingSelection method to grab the selected value. The dateChange event fires on its request.